# Teradata JDBC Warning 3932 Issue

Tags: sql, jdbc, logstash, teradata

I can't get my Teradata sql transaction to work through a logstash file.

I am running a somewhat complex transaction with multiple statements (some of them DDL) relying upon previous statements in Teradata. I’m using the jdbc input plugin in logstash. The statement creates multiple volatile tables to provide columns of information upon which I call upon in later statements to complete the transaction. This transaction works perfectly fine when run in Teradata Studio, but has yet to work when I've tried to run it through a jdbc.conf file.

When I run the transaction through my config file from the command line I receive error message *3932* which essentially tells me that I need to enter in COMMIT statements after my volatile tables. I have looked into the error and have, to no productive success tried:
entering in COMMIT statements after each volatile table
placed BT and Et at the beginning and end of the transaction
changed modes within Teradata jdbc_connection_string parameters vector in hopes of having auto commit enabled (not sure if it is disabled or not).

I know the only issue is my transaction through the jdbc, as I (as mentioned before) have gotten the transaction to work in Teradata, and have successfully run my jdbc.conf file with a simpler query.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When the parser complains about missing COMMITs you run your session in ANSI mode. To switch to BT/ET mode you must specify TMODE=TERA connection parameter.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but unfortunately setting TMODE=TERA, and placing the BT/ET and the beginning and the end of the transaction did not work. Could have been my misproper user of BT/ET, do I just place them once each, BT at the beginning, and ET at the end of my transaction?

Comment: Any DDL must be commited in Teradata immediately and in a Teradata mode session each request is auto-commited, so no need for BT/ET. Now it depends on how the statements are submitted, when each is submitted individually -> individual request -> ok, when multiple statements (e.g. CREATE/INSERT) are submitted as a single request -> error. See https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference%2FB035-1142-160K%2Fgwc1472241599875.html%23